# Split sentences into separate lines

Tags: bash, awk, tr

I'm trying to split sentences in a file into separate lines using a shell script.

Now I would like to split the strings by !, ? or . . The output should be like this :

The file that I want to read from **my_text.txt** and contains

`you want to learn shell script? First, you want to learn Linux command! then. you can learn shell script.`

Now I would like to split the strings by " ! " or "? " or "."  The output should be like this :

> ```
> you want to learn shell script                 
> First, you want to learn Linux command             
> then           
> you can learn shell script
> ```

I used this script :

```
while read p
do
   echo $p | tr "? ! ." "\n " 
done < my_text.txt
```

But the output is:

> you want to learn shell script
>
> First, you want to learn Linux command then you can learn shell script

Can somebody help?

Comment: wrt `I used this script :` - you should read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call 3 tr commands to split for ? ! and .

```
cat test_string.txt | tr "!" "\n" | tr "?" "\n" | tr "." "\n"
```

Comment: You don't need a [UUOC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html), 3 pipes, and 3 calls to `tr` to do this task and using the wrong quotes like that is asking the shell to interpret the text between the quotes and so some shells with some settings will interpret `!` as a history request.

Answer (score 5):

This could be done in a single `awk` using its global substitution option as follows, written and tested with shown samples only in GNU `awk`. Simply globally substituting `?`,`!`,`.` with new line(by default `ORS`(output record separator) value as new line).

```
awk '{gsub(/\?|!|\./,ORS)} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ sed 's/[!?.]/\n/g' file
you want to learn shell script
 First, you want to learn Linux command
 then
 you can learn shell script
```

Answer (score 2):

Awk is ideal for this:

```
awk -F '[?.!]' '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { print $i } }' file
```

Set the field delimiters to ? or . or ! and then loop through each field and print the entry.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you use `tr`. Both arguments to it should be of the same length, otherwise the second one is extended to length of the first by repeating its last character<sup>*</sup>—that is, in this case, a space—to make one-by-one transliteration possible. In other words, given `? ! .` and `\n`  as arguments, `tr` will replace `?` with a line feed, and `!`,  , and `.` with a space. What you're looking for is I guess:

```
$ tr '?!.' '\n' <file
you want to learn shell script
 First, you want to learn Linux command
 then
 you can learn shell script
```

Or, more portably:

```
tr '?!.' '[\n*]' <file
```

<sup>*This is what GNU `tr` does, POSIX leaves the behavior unspecified when arguments aren't of the same length.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In `gnu-awk` we can get it with `gensub()` function:

```
awk '{print gensub(/([.?!]\s*)/, "\n", "g", $0)}' file
you want to learn shell script
First, you want to learn Linux command
then
you can learn shell script
```

Answer (score 0):

why limit yourself to new line \n being the RS ? Maybe something like this :

- \056 is the period. \040 is space. i'll add the + in case there have
  been legacy practices of typing 2 spaces after each sentence and u
  wanna standardize it.
- I presume question  mark \044 is more frequent
  than exclamation \041. Only reason why i'm using all octal is that
  all those are ones that can wreck havor on a terminal when just a
  slight chance of didn't quoting and escaping properly.
- Unlike FS or RS, OFS/ORS are constant strings (are they?), so typing in the characters will be safe.
- the periods are taken care of by RS. No need special processing. So if the row contains  neither ? nor ! , just print it  as is, and move on (it'll handle the ". \n" )

.

```
mawk 'BEGIN { RS = "[\056][\040]+" ; ORS = ". \n"; 
              FS = "[\044][\040]+";  OFS = "? \n"; }
      ($0 !~ /[\041\044]/) { 
                              print; next; } 
             /[\041]/      { 
                              gsub("[\041][\040]+", "\041 \n"); }  
      ( NF==1 ) || ( $1=$1 )'
```

As fast as mawk is, a gsub ( ) or $1=$1 still costs money, so skip the costly parts unless it actually has a ? or ! mark.

Last line is the fun trick, done *outside the brace brackets. You've already done the ! the line before, so if no ? found (aka NF is 1), then that one evaluates true, which awk will short circuit and not execute part 2 , simply print.

But if you've found any ? marks, the assignment of $1=$1 will re-arrange them in new order, and because it's an assignment operation not equality-compare, it always come back successful if the assignment itself didn't fail, which will also serve as it self's always-true flag to print towards the end.

Answer (score 0):

Awk's record separator variable `RS` should do the trick.

```
echo 'you want to learn shell script? First, you want to learn Linux command! then. you can learn shell script.' |
awk 'BEGIN{RS="[?.!] "}1'
```